# Is it possible to use ts_stat with parameterized query Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, word-cloud

I'm trying to use `ts_stat` from PostgreSQL on a `ts_vector` column. The problem is that I need to protect it from SQL injections, so I can't use "concat" string or replace ? to pass a "normal query" to `ts_stat`.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat($$ SELECT tsv_column FROM table where otherColumn ILIKE ? $$)
```

I'm using node.js with https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg to do the query. The ultimate goal is to be able to query a word and the count of its appearances like so:

word  - count

apple - 650025

cookie - 1500

I'll use them as a word cloud. If you have other ideas that could help me doing this I'm open minded, but it needs to be pretty fast (maximum 6 seconds on a database with 80,000 entries on a column that contains a chunk of text). Right now I'm able to get what I want in 5 - 6 seconds but the query can't be parameterized and it needs to be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "format" function.

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat(format($$ SELECT tsv_column FROM table where otherColumn ILIKE %L $$,user_value_here));
```

This won't protect the special meaning of user-supplied _ or %, but if you wanted to disallow those special meanings you probably shouldn't use ILIKE in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WITH` clause to create previously a virtual table.

```
WITH terms AS (SELECT tsv_column FROM table WHERE otherColumn ILIKE ?)
SELECT * FROM ts_stat($$ SELECT tsv_column FROM terms $$);
```

The `WITH` clause creates a virtual temporary table for the specific select that you can use inside the main select.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems like terms is not define inside the st_stat subquery. I've just tried it and got this error : relation "terms" does not exist